# Creating an access point from a connection coming out of a network switch

Tags: networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point, switch

I'm puzzled at the moment, and I'm hoping you can help! The problem is that I'm experiencing on/off connection issues through my current setup and I'm assuming it's because my configuration isn't correct.

So... some context. The building has a primary router from the ISP (HITRON CGNV4). This router has one ethernet cable connected to the network switch (TP-LINK TL-SG1016DE), and then there are 9 other ethernet cables coming out of the network switch which are wired to 9 cat6 wall sockets (one in each apartment).

To provide Wi-Fi in the areas the primary router doesn't reach, there is a router (TL-WR841N) that has been configured to be an access point, offering further wired/wireless connections. This router is connected to one of those aforementioned cat6 wall sockets.

The problem is that this doesn't quite work right. The wireless connections sometimes stop working (however they will stay connected, just with no internet). I'm guessing it might be due to some internal IP conflicts but I know very little about this subject.

[My expertly drawn diagram of how everything is linked...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahSQ5.png)

Comment: Do both access points use the same SSID? Do any _wired_ devices connected to the TL-WR's yellow ports have Internet access? Does a wired device connected directly to the wall-socket have Internet access?

Comment: Access points have different SSIDs. All wired devices connected to the TL-WR's yellow ports have Internet access (there's a laptop and a computer hardwired in atm). Previously when a wired device has been connected to the wall-socket, that device has worked fine.

If I connect an apartment wall-socket directly to the router, and turn off the network switch, everything works as expected. The problem only comes when the switch is online.

Comment: Try using another switch. It sounds like yours may be defective.

Comment: How did you set the router up as an AP? Most consumer APs only have WiFi connectivity and an ethernet port. No NAT, DHCP, Routing, or other stuff.... Most routers refuse to activate wifi while NAT is deactivated because un-NATed WiFi could (in many cases, but not yours) become a HUGE risk to all connected devices. The reason I ask, is that dual NATin could confuse some cheap devices. This could lead to weird connectivity problems now and then.

Comment: If NAT is disabled, but DHCP isn't: That will lead to worse problems. Lost packets/colisions due to IP-conflicts all the time. IF you run double NATs, mke sure you set a public DNS server like 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 in the config of your second router to avoid slow DNS queries.

Answer (score 0):

The overall configuration seems okay. From your description…

> If I connect an apartment wall-socket directly to the router, and turn off the network switch, everything works as expected. The problem only comes when the switch is online.

…I would guess that the switch is dying. (This is not uncommon, especially if the switch happens to be ⪆10 years old. But I don't know why it would happen with your relatively new one.)

Since you have a managed switch, which has a web interface with statistics (and possibly error reports), try taking a look at those. Does the port connected to this particular apartment report many receive errors, or something similar? Does it start working if you disable and re-enable just the single port through webUI?